# How to call a super constructor from another inherited class?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-constructors

I have been instructed to do the following:

- Create a constructor with no arguments in Carnivore that call the super constructor in Animal.

Carnivore is a sub class of Animal which is the super class. so I am looking to call the constructor in Animal within Carnivore. Here is the code:

**Animal super-class**

```
abstract public class Animal 
{

    int age;
    String name;
    String noise;

Animal(String name, int age)   
{
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
} 

Animal()
{
  this("newborn", 0); //This is the super class that needs to be called in Carnivore.
}

}
```

**Carnivore sub-class**

```
public class Carnivore extends Animal
{

   Carnivore()
{
   //Call Animal super constructor
}

}
```

I haven't worked with inheritance before so I'm still getting to grips with it. Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `super()` to call super class constructor as shown below:

```
public class Carnivore extends Animal {

  Carnivore() {
    super(); //calls Animal() no-argument constructor
  }
}
```

> With super(), the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With
>   super(parameter list), the superclass constructor with a matching
>   parameter list is called.

I recommend you to refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) to understand the basics of inheritance and `super`.